# How can I get "Sign out everywhere" activity logs from Microsoft?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a Azure AD tenant and I have created a multitenant client application in it for getting consent from the customers.

The multitenant client application has a Front-channel logout URL(I have used an example logout url for this question)

[image]

If a customer sign in and give consent to my above client application and after that want to sign out everywhere, customer will just click the below button which is in https://myaccount.microsoft.com/ page.

[image]

After that a GET request will send to Front-channel logout URL.

Until now, everything is worked properly. However I want to check and get logs of this "Sign out everywhere" activity logs.

Is this logs/activity reports exposed from Microsoft/Azure for this activity?

Can I access these logs from my tenant which has the client application or can customer who click the "Sign out everywhere" button access this logs?

Comment: I don't think we can get logs on Sign out or Sign out everywhere in microsoft logs

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the front-channel logout requests, clicking "Sign out everywhere" also sets the user's **signInSessionsValidFromDateTime** property (as it's called in Microsoft Graph) to the current time, which has the effect that all previously-issued refresh tokens and browser sessions will no longer be considered valid.

This action of invalidating sessions and refresh tokens is captured in the Azure AD audit logs in an "Update user" event where the *StsRefreshTokensValidFrom* property is changed, and another time in a "Update StsRefreshTokenValidFrom Timestamp" event.

Note that it's possible for that audit event to show up without clicking "Sign out everywhere". For example, using [Revoke-MgUserSign](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users.actions/revoke-mgusersign?view=graph-powershell-1.0), which would *not* trigger the front-channel logout requests.

And of course, also note that it's possible for there to be front-channel logout requests which do not have that audit event, because they do not invalidate all sessions (e.g. a "normal" sign out). Currently, there are no audit or sign-in logs capturing all logout requests (or the subsequent front-channel logouts).